# What's wrong with this fetch request?

Tags: ajax, fetch

```
    let path=`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London`;
    let apiKey=  `&APPID=758bab291826491e79f93979de2ba255`
    let url= path+apiKey;


  function getWeather(url){
     return fetch(url)
        .then(response=> response.json())
        .then(data=>console.log(data))
        .catch(err=> console.log(err))

  }

getWeather();
```

im getting this in the console

[image]
I cant figure it out, i'm very new to this. Its saying 404 but if I copy the URL and go to it it shows the JSON data

err after adding https://
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
let path = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London`;
let apiKey = `&APPID=758bab291826491e79f93979de2ba255`;
let targetURL = path + apiKey;

function getWeather(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

getWeather(targetURL);
```

so there are 2 problems with your initial question:

1. when you do a fetch it tries to do the fetch from the domain the the
   app is currently in. Which is why you're getting 127.0.0.1:5000
   (localhost), if you supply https:// it should not do that.
2. you were not passing in the url to the getWeather(url) function that
   you had declared. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much, would you mind explaining where i went wrong?

Comment: i edited the answer above. There were 2 issues :). you can still do the path + url like you had before as well. that wasnt part of the issue.

Comment: ill edit the answer again so that it reflect more what you had originally wwrote. i simply had simplified the original problem to make understanding the problem easier for myself. just a minute and you should see a new edit.

Comment: the new edit is very close to what you originally had except with the 2 small fixes needed!

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
let path=`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London`;
let apiKey=`&APPID=758bab291826491e79f93979de2ba255`
let url=path+apiKey;

function getWeather(url){
  return fetch(url)
  .then(response=> response.json())
  .then(data=>console.log(data))
  .catch(err=> console.log(err))
}

getWeather();
```

This should work. why? Because when you do a fetch it tries to do the fetch from the domain the the app is currently in. Which is why you're getting 127.0.0.1:5000 (localhost), if you supply https:// it should not do that.

Comment: what does the GET in the console show now for the url?

Comment: added photo to post

Comment: sorry about that i submitted a different answer and it works in my browser now. so that other answer should work for you.